# RJCP.IO.Ports SerialPortsStream System.IO.IOException - Invalid configuration (BreakState, Length, Position)

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, serial-port

I am currently working on a simple WPF application for serial data acquisition from an Arduino Mega Board (for testing purposes at this time, to be scaled to other serial devices).

Environment and packages:

- Target Framework: .NET Framework 4.8, Visual Studio 2019
- SerialPortStream (by Jason Curl - RJCP) version: 2.3.1

Please note that I recently started playing around with C# and I am more familiar with C++ ;)

My app searches and fills the serial ports present in my PC on a ListBox upon loading, then I must select the desired port from the ListBox and open it with a Button. Its callback configures the `SerialPortStream` object.

[image: Window capture from Serial Ports selection ListBox]

After successfully selecting the port, as seen in the console image below, the following exception is thrown to the console and the app just hangs:

[image: Watch window results for USBPort object]

Therefore, I decided to insert a breakpoint at the beginning of my code, to inspect my `USBPort` object, and the object shows errors in the `Length`, `Static Members` and `Position` properties. Inspecting the same object (`USBPort`) in the method where is configured shows the same errors

[image: Watch window showing USBPort Invalid configuration]

A short snippet of my main application code is the following (the lines marked with (*) represent my inserted breakpoints for debugging):

```
using RJCP.IO.Ports;
using System;  
// ... and others

myApp{

    public partial class MainWindow: Window {
    
    private string ComPortName;
    private int BaudRate;
    private SerialPortStream USBPort = new SerialPortStream();
    // ... plus other declarations
    
    public MainWindow(){

        InitializeComponent();

        (*) BaudRate = 115200;    // Inserted a breakpoint here to inspect USBPort in the debugger
    }

    // Start communication Callback/Binding --> Connect button Click binding
    private void StartCOM_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){

        try{
            
            (*) USBPort = new SerialPortStream(ComPortName, BaudRate);
            USBPort.Open(); // Inserting a breakpoint here shows the same errors in the watch window

            // ...subsequent actions


        } catch(Exception ex){
             if(ex is IOException){

                 throw new IOException("Unable to create serial port");  // Message does NOT get displayed
             
             }

        } 
}
```

Please note that my approach USED to work just fine and I was able to read lines from the serial port. Something broke after I refactored some parts of my code NOT related to the `SerialPortStream` object. I even tried with an old version of my code and now it keeps throwing the same error every time.

- Is my way of pre-declaring my `USBPort` object using the empty constructor, then configuring it inside the callback correct?
- What is the "specified method" that the `Length` property refers to?
- Does the RJCP dll strongly depend on the framework used? According to the GitHub [repo](https://github.com/jcurl/RJCP.DLL.SerialPortStream), it *should* work fine in 4.8.
- Are different Windows 10 versions related to this issue? My code worked fine yesterday on my laptop at work and it doesn't on my Home's PC. (At the moment I have no access to that laptop).
- Should I fall back to previous versions of the RJCP package?

Answer (score 1):

Going over your individual questions:

- Is my way of pre-declaring my USBPort object using the empty constructor, then configuring it inside the callback correct?

  - Yes. This is fine. They're just properties until the port is Open()ed.
  - But your code snippet you provide ignores this, because in `StartCOM_Click` you instantiate a new instance of `SerialPortStream` anyway. Check that you haven't opened the same port twice, which may lead to a resource conflict (Windows doesn't allow opening the same serial port from one or more applications more than once).
- What is the "specified method" that the Length property refers to?

  - The `Length` and `Position` property are not defined, that the `CanSeek` property is `false` in this particular implementation.
- Does the RJCP dll strongly depend on the framework used? According to the GitHub repo, it should work fine in 4.8.

  - Using package 2.3.1 has libraries for .NET 4.0, .NET 4.5 and .NET Standard 1.5. The NuGet package manager should be choosing the .NET 4.5 compiled version when running on top of .NET 4.8 which is described by [Supporting Multiple Target Frameworks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks.).
  - you can confirm this by checking the library `RJCP.SerialPortStream.dll` that is given next to your compiled program. Just check the sizes. The .NET 4.5 version is 233kB, the .NET Standard version is 246kB.
  - You probably know that the runtime itself, if you have .NET 4.8 installed, is a high compatibility in place upgrade for all other versions. So software targetting .NET 4.5 or .NET 4.8 runs essentially the same code underneath (I say essentially, because MS does have some compatibility checks, but they aren't relevant here).
- Are different Windows 10 versions related to this issue? My code worked fine yesterday on my laptop at work and it doesn't on my Home's PC. (At the moment I have no access to that laptop).

  - It's more likely that this is related to the driver itself, not liking something in particular. Unfortunately, from the description given, it's difficult to tell what. To debug this, it's best to track in the [GitHub](https://github.com/jcurl/RJCP.DLL.SerialPortStream/issues/129) issue.
- Should I fall back to previous versions of the RJCP package?

  - There has been a few bugfixes, etc. but nothing described here that suggests this would make a difference.

Comment: Dear Jason.  Thank you very much for the comprehensive response. I can confirm that I am Open()ing the port only once through a Button(). Indeed, the failure point seems to be in the Open() method (again, in the Ryzen PC only). Let's continue the conversation on GitHub, if you agree (and if the SOVF Admins agree)

Comment: For anyone interested in this specific case, I will come back here and post the solution as soon as I have it, with Jason's help. ;)